# Assign unique file name to downloaded data while making API calls

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests, urllib3

I have a API calling function which takes in a URL as function parameter. The function makes a GET request to the URL and saves data as a csv file at in a given directory.

The URL being passed is made up of several parameters such as AccountID, fromDate, toDate, etc. I have 100 URLs to download data from and would like to have 100 individual .csv files. What is the best way to create the .csv title on the fly each time the API calling function is called.

Until now, I was just grabbing the AccountID from the URL and using that as .csv file titles. However, sometimes the AccountID is same, but other parameters are different in the URL. What's the best way of doing this? I don't want any of the .csv files to be overwritten.

Note: I'm using Python 3.7 with the following packages - requests, urllib.parse, json.

Thanks!

Comment: You can name the csv file with timestamp, so that everything will be unique always!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that -- but I'm creating dataframes out of all those .csv files. Right now, it is just easy to correlate the dataframe with AccoutID, so I know which data my code is working with internally. With timestamps, how would I maintain the .csv::AccountID mapping?

Comment: Can you post your code so that i can help you better?

Comment: you can use Python uuid3 to generate unique hash values and concatenate them to the AccountID https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: I think that would be similar to concatenating timestamps in file title. But the problem is this. Let's say the accountID is called 'XYZ' and assume the UUID is a 6 digit integer for convenience here. Now when i add a UUID/timestamp to my file title, it would be something like 'XYZ123654.csv'. For another call to the same accountID with different 'fromDate, toDate' parameters, the new dataset downloaded will be called 'XYZ988333'. Now when I create dataframes from these 2 .csv files, how will I know which dataframe corresponds to the first .csv and which corresponds to the second .csv file?

Comment: Just add increasing numeric ID as prefix 1_XYZ123654.csv    2_XYZ988333  etc